Как проверить, существует ли файл без исключений?
Как проверить, существует ли файл или нет, без использования оператора try-except?
Я не люблю громоздкие конструкции, поэтому если существует способ их избегать - стараюсь. Для меня использование условных конструкций вместо обработки исключений может делает код более понятным и простым для чтения

Есть, os.path.exists или Path.exists. Но это ненадежно, между проверкой наличия и фактическим обращением внешний мир может внезапно измениться.

реализовать функцию, в которой будет try/except и просто вызывать её?

Это можно сделать с помощью встроенного модуля os, вы правы, правильнее избегать использование try-except в подобных случаях.
import os


if os.path.exists('your_path'):
    print('File exists')
else:
    print('File does not exist')


а не могли бы вы объяснить в своем ответе, почему прям "правильнее избегать использования try-except в подобных случаях"?

Ибо скорее то наоборот - проблема (любая - файл удалили, нет доступа, отвалилась шара, да мало ли) может случиться именно в момент открытия файла, уже после любых проверок, и тут ничего кроме try/except не спасёт.

@CrazyElf нет доступа и отвалилась шара это другие виды исключений, предлагаете городить трёхэтажные конструкции с try-except, учитывая то, что файлы обычно открываются с помощью контекстного менеджера?

Я не так выразился, вероятно. Стоит отталкиваться от задачи)

"предлагаете городить трёхэтажные конструкции с try-except, учитывая то, что файлы обычно открываются с помощью контекстного менеджера?" - точно так же придется делать несколько проверок через if на каждый возможный случай, и все равно в контекстном менеджере упадет из-за какого-то необработанного случая. "Трехэтажность" с try-except состоит только в дополнительном уровне вложенности. Этот дополнительный уровень вложенности легко можно спрятать за каким-нибудь декоратором или можно вынести часть кода в отдельную функцию.

В простом случае можно вообще ничего не отлавливать и не проверять, а например просто добавить снаружи функции логирование с помощью какого-нибудь @catch из loguru: https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.catch

Например так?
import os.path


if os.path.exists("python.exe"):
    print("Файл существует!")
else:
    print("Файла не существует (")

